# SSIS Email Task Attachment Name from Variable

Tags: ssis-2012

I was wondering if I can parameterize the path and file name of an attachment file through SSIS Email Task.

Waiting for your kind response.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind :)

I found the solution which is simply right click on the Email Task and from expressions you can find "Attachments" and from there you can set a variable.